# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm relatively new to Android development and am writing my first REST-based app.  I've opted to use the [Android Asynchronous HTTP Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to make things a bit easier.  I'm currently just running through the main "Recommended Usage" section on that link, essentially just creating a basic static HTTP client.  I'm following the code given, but changing it around to refer to a different API.  Here's the code in question:

```
    public void getFactualResults() throws JSONException {
    FactualRestClient.get("q=Coffee,Los Angeles", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray venues) {
            // Pull out the first restaurant from the returned search results
            JSONObject firstVenue = venues.get(0);
            String venueName = firstVenue.getString("name");

            // Do something with the response
            System.out.println(venueName);

        }
    });
}
```

The `String venueName = firstVenue.getString("name");` line is currently throwing an error in Eclipse: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to JSONObject".  Why is this error occurring?  I searched other threads which led me to try using `getJSONObject(0)` instead of `get(0)` but that led to further errors and Eclipse suggesting using try/catch.  I haven't changed any of the code on the tutorial, save for the variable names and URL.  Any thoughts/tips/advice?

Thanks so much.

EDIT:

Here is the onSuccess method, modified to include the try/catch blocks suggested.  Eclipse now shows the "local variable may not have been initialized" for firstVenue here: `venueName = firstVenue.getString("name");` and for venueName here: `System.out.println(venueName);`  Even if I initialize `String venueName;` directly after `JSONObject firstVenue;` I still get the same error.  Any help in resolving these would be greatly appreciated!

```
public void onSuccess(JSONArray venues) {
            // Pull out the first restaurant from the returned search results
            JSONObject firstVenue;
            try {
                firstVenue = venues.getJSONObject(0);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String venueName;
            try {
                venueName = firstVenue.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Do something with the response
            System.out.println(venueName);

        }
```

Comment: can you please paste your venues value that you retrieve by get request?

Comment: Use GSON from google as it is easy, fast, light weight and takes all the pain of this away https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be using `getJSONObject` to ensure that the value you obtain is a JSON object. And yes, you should catch the possible `JSONException` which is thrown if that index in the array doesn't exist, or does not contain an object.

It'll look something like this:

```
JSONObject firstVenue;
try {
    firstVenue = venues.get(0);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  So the error handling in line 1 does not help then?  Can that just be removed?  The `FactualRestClient.get()` is defined as this:   `public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
       client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
   }` so it already has error handling built in...  Can you clarify?

Comment: Your existing `throws` clause catches `JSONException`s that are thrown in the `getFactualResults` method, but the exception would occur in the `onSuccess` method of the response handler. So that method would have to throw the exception (which will necessitate modifying the interface and `FactualRestClient`). And even then, because this is asynchronous, you can't throw it within the runtime of `getFactualResults`. Better to catch it in `onSuccess`, or if it's truly unexpected, throw a `RuntimeException` (which is unchecked).

Comment: OK, so I did that, but then I encounter problems with firstVenue and venueName being initialized within the try/catch block - the error is "local variable firstVenue may not have been initialized."  Even if I initialize both before the try/catch, it still happens.  Thoughts?

Comment: You'll have to paste the modified code fragment for me to tell.

Comment: jeremy, I added the modified code fragment in the bottom of the body of the original question, as I wanted to keep it as readable as possible.

Comment: Either initialize the variables (before the try-catch or in the catch block, so that `javac` knows for certain they've been initialized) or return from the catch block after printing the stack trace (so that the use becomes unreachable). The latter probably makes sense in this case, as if you fail to get the venue, you probably can't do anything meaningful to attempt to get its name.

Comment: initializing before the catch block worked.  thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert object you are getting from querying to String and then use

final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringresult);

I was getting same error earlier, it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify how that would fit in the existing code?  Thanks

Comment: what are the values of venues u get?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the venues are returned in a JSONArray and are JSONObjects.

Answer (score 0):

convert obj to json Object:

Object obj = JSONValue.parse(inputParam);
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Shail Adi only worked for me by setting the initial values of firstVenue and venueName to null. Here's my code:

```
        JSONObject firstVenue = null;
        try {
            firstVenue = (JSONObject)venues.get(0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String venueName = null;
        try {
            venueName = firstVenue.getString("name");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Do something with the response
        System.out.println(venueName);
```